# php number operations

Tags: php, numbers

I have problems to get my percent counter function to get it work with English money format

```
function calc_proc($price, $savings) {
    $old_price = $price + $savings;

    return (number_format($savings / ($old_price/100)));
}
```

because of the commas I'm getting bad values

Comment: Include some examples ..

Comment: can you show your present output example?

Comment: and what is your expected output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't have to use strings in financial calculations but if you still have to use, you should replace commas with dots. For example,

```
$a = '1,5';
$b = '2,1';
echo $a + $b; //result 3

// you can avoid this, by replacing comma:
$a = str_replace(',', '.', $a);
//same for $b
```

Another solution could be setting locale but you'd have issues with dots after that.

In your function it'll look like this:

```
function calc_proc($price, $savings) {
    $price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);
    $savings = str_replace(',', '.', $savings);
    $old_price = (float)$price + (float)$savings;

    return (number_format($savings / ($old_price/100)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is english money format something like this: 253,17?

If yes, then simply do:

```
str_replace(',', '.', $value);
```

Then you're safe.

Answer (score 0):

Try `setlocale(constant, location)` at the beginning of your script. In your case:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"En-Us");
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP number_format() function without parameters return english format with comma. You should instead use:

```
return round($savings / ($old_price/100), 0);
```

and make sure $old_price cant be 0

Answer (score 0):

```
function percent($price, $savings) {
  $count1 = str_replace(',', '.', $price)/ $savings;
  $count2 = $count1 * 100;
  $count = number_format($count2, 0);
  return $count;
}
```